# Trying to run application locally, application is working fine in Cloud-dev environment but throwing 404 in cloud-stage

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, development-environment

Application showing 404 not found in cloud-stage environment, request link seems to be fine

enter image description here
This is the error
[this is stage property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy5ox.png)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Which link are you testing?

Comment: its a pcp server url for healthcheck.